# Outputting requests onto console in a LAMP stack

Tags: php, lamp

I am trying to setup my first website and want to see the requests to my web server. I've been trying to google my question and haven't found any useful links. I have a LAMP stack set up and was wondering if there was a way to output to the console all the requests that my website receives.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of commands to achieve what you want, e.g. to see last logs (you can `| grep` for more specific output):

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

For Ubuntu/Debian you can also try `apachetop`:

```
sudo apt-get install apachetop
```

then use it like so (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/apachetop.1.html), *refresh every 5 seconds, show all requests in last minute*:

```
apachetop -r 5 -T 60
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where would these code snippets go? The only code I really have is my .html and .php files that I serve to the browser. Is it possible to do this real time as I receive the requests?

Comment: You should make these changes on server, where your LAMP is set up. BTW, I assume you have Linux-based hosting, therefore above commands will works on ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

[https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog](http://logs)

use this package then log your request into logs and check them .

this is just near to me , i hope someone will give you best ans.